# Issue with Telerik grid and Entity Framework Core (.NET)

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, telerik, blazor

I started working with Blazor few weeks ago and recently got introduced to Telerik UI for Blazor so I started making a CRUD to learn.

After coding the update function I tested the app and got this error when I tried to update a register:

```
The instance of entity type 'Familia' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'CodiFamilia'} is already being tracked.
```

To solve that I added "AsNoTracking" to the Entity Framework Core query located in "ReadList", it worked the first time but the app crashed after the second update. Afterwards I implemented an alternative solution which consists on finding the object by its ID and updating every parameter one by one which worked since it's not using the same object.

I'm wondering if there is any way to implement a functional update which resembles the first solution because the second one is pretty bad if there are many parameters to update. Here is the [Gist](https://gist.github.com/deividgp/f923cfb8525dbce4fe39c10c6fd0f60e).

Thanks in advance :) .

Comment: Without a full set of code to run and debug I can't be sure what the Telerik control is passing back as `args.Item` - I don't personally use Telerik.  Entity Framework obviously doesn't like it!  The working code works because the updates take place on the object retrieved from EF.

However, you should consider using a DBContextFactory for your DbContexts.  Running async EF operations on a single context has it's problems.  The MS-Docs article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/) is the best reference on the subject.

Comment: https://entityframeworkcore.com/draft-querying-data-asnotracking